# HtmlUnit to click on specific link from link's reference with same name

Tags: java, html, regex, htmlunit

I started using HtmlUnit today, so I'm a bit noob at the time.

I've managed to to go to IMDB and search for the movie "Sleepers" from 1996, and I get a bunch of results with the same name:

[Here are the results from that search](http://www.imdb.com/find?q=sleepers&s=tt)

I want to select the first "Sleepers" from the list, which is the correct one, but I don't know how to get that information with HtmlUnit. I looked inside the code and found the link, but I don't know how to extract it.

I guess i could use some regex, but that would defeat the purpose of using HtmlUnit.

This is my code (It has some bits from HtmlUnit's tutorial and some code found here):

```
public IMdB() {
    try {
        //final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_8, "10.255.10.34", 8080);

        //set proxy username and password 
        final DefaultCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = (DefaultCredentialsProvider) webClient.getCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.addCredentials("xxxx", "xxxx");

        // Get the first page
        final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://www.imdb.com");

        // Get the form that we are dealing with and within that form, 
        // find the submit button and the field that we want to change.
        //final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("navbar-form");
        HtmlForm form = page1.getFirstByXPath("//form[@id='navbar-form']");

        //
        HtmlButton button = form.getFirstByXPath("/html/body//form//button[@id='navbar-submit-button']");            
        HtmlTextInput textField = form.getFirstByXPath("/html/body//form//input[@id='navbar-query']");

        // Change the value of the text field
        textField.setValueAttribute("Sleepers");

        // Now submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.
        HtmlPage page2 = button.click();

       // form = page2.getElementByName("s");

        //page2 = page2.getFirstByXPath("/html/body//form//div//tr[@href]");

        System.out.println("content: " + page2.asText());

        webClient.closeAllWindows();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(IMdB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    System.out.println("END");
}
```

Comment: were you able to use the suggestion?

Comment: no, because it was not what i was looking for, but thanks anyway. I finally used some regex to extract some specific data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do that this way:

```
HtmlPage htmlPage = new WebClient().getPage("http://imdb.com/blah");
HtmlAnchor anchor = htmlPage.getFirstByXPath("//td[@class='primary_photo']//a")
System.out.println(anchor.getHrefAttribute());
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this. I've managed to extract some specific data using regex, but I think HtmlUnit has some tools for this type of thing.

Comment: How i would extract the "Sleepers" part from this:  `<td class="title">
    

<span class="wlb_wrapper" data-tconst="tt0117665" data-size="small" data-caller-name="search"></span>

    <a href="/title/tt0117665/">Sleepers</a>
    <span class="year_type">(1996)</span><br>
<div class="user_rating">`? My program is working fine. It finds the movie, cast, nominations, rating, etc... but through regex.

Comment: Regex is clearly NOT the way to go. Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348) and the first answer. I'd recommend you use XPath. You'll find many tutorials on google.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that, but I think regex (even though is not the best way to do it) works well for simple things. I've already have my program working and fetching information with regex (until i learn how to use xpath9).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to rather use the `IMDB api` then doing all that

The IMDb currently has two public APIs that are, although undocumented, very quick and reliable (used on their own site through AJAX).

1. A statically cached search suggestions API:

   - http://sg.media-imdb.com/suggests/a/aa.json
   - http://sg.media-imdb.com/suggests/h/hello.json
   - Format: JSONP
2. More advanced search

   - Name search (json): http://www.imdb.com/xml/find?json=1&nr=1&nm=on&q=jeniffer+garner
   - Title search (xml): http://www.imdb.com/xml/find?xml=1&nr=1&tt=on&q=lost
   - Format: JSON, XML and more

Comment: I think his intention is to learn to use HtmlUnit rather than extracting data from IMDB.

Comment: @MostyMostacho okay maybe, I inferred otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, that was the idea, but thanks anyway. It's good to know about it.